# OAuth2 in Rails - Outlook 365 API sending extra parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, office365

I am attempting to communicate with the Office 365 API from a Rails 5 application.  I'm having trouble requesting the 'scopes' that I need. According to this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-compare/ , I need to send the scopes as an extra parameter in the request.  I have added the scopes to the application registration at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ but this doesn't seem to be enough.  The scopes that I'm trying to request are Calendar.ReadWrite and offline_access. Using the OAuth2 ruby gem, how can I send these scopes as part of the request? I am creating my OAuth client as follows:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['APPLICATION_ID_OUTLOOK_API'],
                            ENV['APPLICATION_ID_OUTLOOK_SECRET'],
                            :site => "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
                            :authorize_url => "/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
                            :token_url => "/common/oauth2/token")
```

I've tried adding another hash to this constructor as follows:

```
 :scope => "https://outlook.office.com/calendar.readwrite https://outlook.office.com/offline_access"
```

But this doesn't work.

My intention is to use the outlook_ruby gem to read and write to calendars.  This gem, as far as i know, requires the outlook.office.com scopes to operate.  Currently when I attempt to perform any function with the OAuth token I get back from this request, I recieve a 401 Unauthorized message.